# How to count all objects in Database via Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

What I'd like to do is count all objects in the database. I started with something like this:

`p ["TOTAL COUNT", ApplicationRecord.subclasses.sum(&:count)]`

But while experimenting I found...

`[5] pry(main)> ApplicationRecord.subclasses.count => 6`

Which I expected to return a lot more than that. I can inspect the subclasses and find that some are missing.

Then I found....

`[8] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.count => 10`

Which added a few more. Again I can inspect them individually, and I noticed a few were missing. Here is an example of one that is missing...

```
class MerchantsPrincipal < ApplicationRecord  
end

class Principal < MerchantsPrincipal 
end
```

How can I make sure those are also included?

Comment: Sorry ,why you need this? Maybe if you describe full business case, it help to resolve it with normal solution. Because you question is little bit strange.

Comment: Also, what you mean when said "all objects"? All domains (AR classes) or all rows in all tables in your database (all AR instanses)?

Comment: @MaxVinogradov I'm looking for all AR instances or rows in the table. I have a cucumber suite that is an absolute mess and I suspect is very slow because of using Factories that create way more objects than necessary. I want to the find the worst offenders of object creation and see if I can fix those tests first. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've not worked with cucumber yet. But I can say that usually AR count != Rows in table. Because ARs created dynamically, that can be removed or cached by Rails ORM.

Comment: And, I don't know what test you have, but maybe it's reasonable to mock db record-entities ?

Comment: Note that `MerchantsPrincipal.count` already includes `Principal.count` because of how STI works so `descendants` is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @MaxVinogradov You're exactly right. Some of them could be mocked and/or just not created. I have a lot of factories that say create a company with them. So every time a product or user or any number of things are created a company is created with. I'm just trying to figure out if I can hone in on the problem ones and focus on the biggest wins first.

Comment: You could use fixtures for "static" data (i.e. data that is not meant to be changed) and refer it in your factories. For example, if you need a User record with Admin role, you could create a fixture for that use and then define the relation in your factories as `user { ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify("key_you_used_in_the_yml") }`

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer for your question, but a suggestion for you in order to speed up your test suite.

You can do some caching with FactoryGirl, something like this:

```
class RecordCache
  def self.[](key)
    all.fetch(key)
  end

  def self.register(name, object)
    all[name] = object
  end

  def self.setup!
    register :admin_user, FactoryGirl.create(:user, is_admin: true)
  end

  private

  def all
    @all ||= {}
  end
end
```

Then you need to call `RecordCache.setup!` in your `test_helper.rb` before running your test suite.

After that, you will be able to ask this `RecordCache` to provide the instance instead of making FactoryGirl create it again:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    # title content etc.
    user { RecordCache[:admin_user] }
  end
end
```

So that every time you call `FactoryGirl.create(:post)`, it does not create another user. This brings some concerns, as the same record is cached through the app and should not be modified. But if you want a specific user for a specific context, you can still do:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: FactoryGirl.create(:user, :super_admin))
```